# Horizontal Line with a down arrow in the center

Tags: arrows, line, center, horizontal

To describe transformations from certain programming constructs into e.g. assembler I need a horizontal line with a downward pointing arrow in the center of the line.

Is there also a way to achieve this without tikz?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without `TikZ`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}   
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \rule{5cm}{0.4pt}\raisebox{-.1cm}{$\Downarrow$}\rule{5cm}{0.4pt}   
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using, instead, `TikZ`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}   
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw    (100,122) -- (260,122) ;
\draw    (268,122) -- (428,122) ;
\draw (254,110) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\LARGE]  {$\Downarrow $};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]